# Google Maps Services and Facebook Java version issue on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, facebook, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm getting this warning:

```
Warning:com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdate.class(com/google/android/gms/maps:CameraUpdate.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
```

It seems `Google Maps Services` recommend me to compile with `Java 1.7`, but as per `Facebook` documentation, `Facebook SDK` should be compiled on `Java 1.6`.

What should I do: should I compile with `1.6` and ignore the warning; should I compile with `1.7` cause it will work flawless with `Facebook SDK` even the docs says 1.6;  or is there a way to compile `Facebook SDK` with `1.6` and the rest of the project with `1.7`?

Comment: any solution to this, same issue i faced today